# How can i show my products cards in horizontally?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

**ProductsCard**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Card, Container, Row, Col, ListGroup, Button} from 'react-bootstrap'

function ProductCard(props){
    return(
        <div>
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Col md={3} xs={6}>
                        <Card border="primary" style={{widht:'14rem'}}>
                            <Card.Img variant="top" src={props.product.image}/>
                            <Card.Body>
                                <Card.Title>{props.product.name}</Card.Title>
                                <Card.Text>Price: ${props.product.price}, Quantity: {props.product.quantity}
                                </Card.Text>
                                <Button variant="primary">Add to Cart</Button>
                            </Card.Body>
                        </Card>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default ProductCard
```

**Home**

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {Container, Row, Col, Image, Card, Button, CardDeck} from 'react-bootstrap';
import axios from 'axios';
import ProductCard from './ProductCard';

    enter code here


function Home(){
    const url = 'http://localhost:8888/ProgWeb/public/api/products'
    const [product, setProduct]=useState({
        loading: false,
        data: null,
        error: false
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        setProduct({
            loading:true,
            data: null,
            error: false
        })
        axios.get(url)
        .then(response => {
            setProduct({
                loading: false,
                data: response.data,
                error: false
            })
        })
        .catch(() =>{
            setProduct({
                loading: false,
                data: null,
                error: true
            })
        })



    }, [url])

    let content = null

    if(product.data){
        content = 
        product.data.map((product, key) => 
            <div  key={product.id}>
                <ProductCard
                product={product} 
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
  
    return (
        <div>
        {content}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

Now this is my first time using react-bootstrap. So I don't have much clue here.

What I want is for the cards to be generated in such a way that there are THREE cards in a row.

Now this is the code that I have done so far, but I am confused on how can I make the cards horizontal, I already typed  in bootstrap but I still get the products vertically

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I display 3 card components horizontally with react bootstrap and grids?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62533219/how-do-i-display-3-card-components-horizontally-with-react-bootstrap-and-grids)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In your ProductsCard component, Give your div container an id, it can be anything. Example:

```
function ProductCard(props){
   return(
       <div id=“unique-name”>
           <Container>
               <Row>
                    ...
               </Row>
           </Container>
           
       </div>
   )
}
```

2. Now go to your css file and add the following:

```
#unique-name {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around

}
```

We are making the Container a flexbox and changing the direction to horizontal.
Reference: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-direction/

ALTERNATIVELY:

You can Simply add class=“row” to the div element like this:

```
if(product.data){
        content = 
        product.data.map((product, key) => 
            <div class=“row” key={product.id}>
   
                <ProductCard
                product={product} 
                />
   
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Then I know the ultimate solution, However its a bit of work. I have used it before and it works

here you go:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62533219/how-do-i-display-3-card-components-horizontally-with-react-bootstrap-and-grids

Comment: It looks like your console has an error logged, Could you share the error?